# Linking a variable with column number

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file in the following format:

```
run-225-1 178.165 178.165 117.025
run-84-7 178.308 178.308 117.028
run-247-2 178.750 178.750 117.110
run-7-7 178.760 178.760 117.117
run-110-5 177.644 177.644 117.121
run-5-5 179.173 179.173 117.121
run-56-7 179.220 179.220 117.131
run-78-1 178.176 178.176 117.167
```

I have used awk to calculate the mean and standard deviation of each numerical column.

I then compare the standard deviations using IF statements to determine which column contains the worst data:

```
if [[ $ASTD > $BSTD ]]; then
    top=$ASTD
else
    top=$BSTD
fi

if [[ $top > $CSTD ]]; then
    BAD=$top
else
    BAD=$CSTD
fi

echo $BAD
```

What I want to do now is subtract the mean from each element in the column with the worst standard deviation ($BAD) (using awk), then append the results of the subtraction as a new column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, I'm at a complete loss on this one. I can subtract the mean of each column from each corresponding column but then I'm still left with the question of how to point sort to the correct column.

Comment: "point sort to the correct column"? Are you trying to subtract from *every* column or just the one "bad" column? What do you have for doing the subtraction so far?

Comment: Just the bad column ideally

basic subtract as 

awk -v AMEAN=${AMEAN} '{$5 = $2 - AMEAN; print}' file.txt

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do it, but I'd start by figuring out which column returns the "worst" standard deviation,

```
if [[ $ASTD > $BSTD ]]; then

top=$ASTD
col=1
else

top=$BSTD
col=2
fi

if [[ $top > $CSTD ]]; then

BAD=$top
else 
BAD=$CSTD
col=3

fi
```

Then pass the col argument on to awk

```
awk -v col=$col bad=$BAD '{print $0, $(col) - bad}' <infile>
```

You may have to futz with the indirection in $(col)

Comment: ahhhhh that looks like what I want to do. I'll test it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ace!

Here's what I've got;

sort cell.txt by agreement with mean, according to A B or C depending on which has the highest standard deviation

if [[ $ASTD > $BSTD ]]; then

```
top=$ASTD
col=2
mean=$AMEAN
```

else
    top=$BSTD
    col=3
    mean=$BMEAN
fi

if [[ $top > $CSTD ]]; then

```
BAD=$top
```

else
    BAD=$CSTD
    col=4
    mean=$CMEAN
fi

echo worst dimension is $col
echo mean is $mean

awk -v column=${col} -v mean=${mean} '{$5 = $(column) - mean; print}' cell.txt >>tmp.txt

sort -k5 -n tmp.txt > sorted.txt

rm tmp.txt

If anyone has a more elegant solution please let me know!